# convergence of improper Integral..

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

I need help finding if the improper integral below converges.

$$\int _{ 2 }^{ \infty  }{ \frac { dx }{ \sqrt [ 3 ]{ 1-{ x }^{ 4 } }  }  } $$.

we learnt at class:
comparison test
ratio test

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the given integral cannot be real. if we do nnot mind then iitt is asymtoically equivalent   to the integral of x ^(-4/3) which exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As $x\to\infty$,
$${1\over \root{3}\of{1-x^4}}
= -{1\over \root{3}\of{x^4-1}}\sim -{1\over x^{4/3}}$$
so the integral converges.

Answer (score 0):

For $x>2, x^{4}-1>\frac{x^{4}}{2}$ holds. Then we have
\begin{align}
\int_{2}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{\sqrt[3]{x^{4}-1}}<2^{4/3}\int_{2}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{x^{4/3}}=2^{4/3}\times 2\times 2^{1/3}=6 
\end{align}
and the integral converges.